# Display Image with "image_tag" from my DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I'm having some issues with my project I'm using the image_tag with my DB but every time I want to use it, is not taking the syntaxis this is the message thar I got **The asset "ur" is not present in the asset pipeline**., this is the code:

```
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
       <%=link_to article_path(article), class:"thumb-link" do %>
           <%= image_tag ("#{article.img}") %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

in my DB in the field "img" I got this URL "https://dummyimage.com/700x900/000/C82E0D.jpg"

any idea where do I have my mistake???

I will really appreciate if you can help me with thi issue

Comment: I check my code again I found my mistake in the image_tag I need to add the https like this: <%= image_tag ("https://#{article.img}") %> and it works

Comment: Consider answering your question so others can benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

I check my code again I found my mistake in the image_tag I need to add the https like this:

`<%= image_tag ("https://#{article.img}") %>`

and it works